# Highcharts bubble chart with date?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, highcharts, highcharts-ng

Has anyone every seen or put together a chart that looks like the image below?  The bubbles would not overlap:

[Bubble chart with date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CruF4.jpg)

Comment: not able to watch image. can you embed in this post ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a category axis type for both - x and y axis.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'bubble'
},

xAxis: {
  categories: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
  opposite: true,
  min: 0,
  max: rows
},

yAxis: {
  categories: ['Feb 19', 'Feb 26', 'Mar 5', 'Mar 12'],
  min: 0,
  max: cols
},
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/L2fkp6ma/